# How to use spring configuration class in a controller function

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have searched multiple pages thru google. It tells you how to load the configuration thru the annotation. But the tutorial always forget how to use the created object in the controller.

Here is my code.

Properties file (demo.properties)

```
demo.out_path=c:\demo_dir
```

Demo Config file (DemoAppConfig.java)

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:demo.properties")
public class DemoAppConfig {

    @Value("${demo.out_path}")
    private String OutPath;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Servlet config (demo-servlet.xml)

```
<!-- Properties -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:demo.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"  />
```

How do I call the properties inside a controller? I tried auto wire annotation of DemoAppConfig as a property but it fails. I tried instantiating the DemoAppConfig as a new class but all property were not loaded.

Note: Used spring version 4.1.7.RELEASE

Comment: I think you want this part in your controller, not the config: `@Value("${demo.out_path}") private String OutPath;` Then the controller can reference the outPath as specified in the properties file.

Comment: @Glenn I already added the value annotation in my controller code and it throws an exception that the property was not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know one way is to configure system property look up in xml config as below:

```
<util:properties id="systemPropertyLookup" location="classpath:demo.properties"/>
```

Of course, you need to add in spring-util schema declaration:

```
<beans ....
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="....
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
```

Then inject your property value into your controller as follow:

```
 @Value("#{systemPropertyLookup['demo.out_path']")
 private String OutPath;
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking my project, this is how I have been loading `persistence.properties` and I have been able to use `@Value` just like you have configured:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = Application.class)
class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        ppc.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/persistence.properties"));
        return ppc;
    }

}
```

Make sure that it is on the classpath and that the compiler copies the resource file into the distributable.